# Explain why matrix $A$ is diagonalizable and find minimal polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, trace, minimal-polynomials

Consider the matrix
$$A = \frac{1}{4}
\begin{bmatrix}
17 & -6 & -9 & -12 
\\ 15 & 26 & 69 & 36
\\ 3 & 6 & 29 & 12
\\ -12 & -12 & -48 & -16
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
I am given that $(A-I)(A-2I)(A-5I)=0$. I have to **explain why this matrix is diagonalizable and then find the minimal polynomial of this matrix.**

For the diagonalizability, I was thinking that since the matrix has 3 distinct eigenvalues, then the minimal polynomial would have 3 distinct linear factors, making this matrix diagonalizable. However I'm not sure how to show this and I'm also not sure if this is necessarily correct.

As for finding the minimal polynomial, I was given a hint that says to use the trace but I don't see the relationship between the two.

Comment: How do you know the matrix has three distinct eigenvalues?  As soon as one of the factors is $0$, it doesn't matter what the other factors are.

Comment: @saulspatz I was using the given equation and the fact that the eigenspace of $A$ is $Null{T-\lambda I}$ which looked like it was satisfied by this equation.

Comment: Suppose the minimal polynomial is $(x-2)(x-5)$.  Then won't $A$ also satisfy $(x-a)(x-2)(x-5)$ for any value of $a$?

Comment: @saulspatz That makes sense, thanks for clearing that up. How should I show that this matrix is diagonalizable?

Comment: One possible way: every factor of the expression is linear and the minimal polynomial divides that expression hence its factors are linear.

Comment: @cgss Thanks for the explanation. Would you know a strategy to actually compute the minimal polynomial?

Comment: The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues.

Comment: The matrix satisfies the polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)(x-5)$; in particular, the minimal polynomial divides $(x-1)(x-2)(x-5)$. That means the minimal polynomial splits and has no repeated roots, hence the matrix is diagonalizable. The minimal polynomial is one of the factors of this polynomial. It is clearly none of $x-1$, $x-2$, or $x-5$. You can check to see if it is any of the degree 2 factors; otherwise, it is the degree 3 polynomial.

Comment: Alternatively, the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, and every eigenvalue must show up in the minimal. If the minimal were, say, $(x-1)(x-2)$, then the eigenvalues would have to be $1,1,1,2$; or $1,1,2,2$; or $1,2,2,2$, so the trace would have to be $5$, $6$, or $7$. Etc.

Comment: Since the trace is $14$ and the eigenvalues can only be $1,2,$ or $5$, $2$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $2$, as is $5$.

Comment: @saulspatz If the trace is the sum of the elements on the main diagonal, wouldn't we have that $traceA = 17+26+29-16=56$?

Comment: @rss What about the factor of $\frac14$?

Comment: @saulspatz Forgot about that, thanks.

Comment: Since the trace is 14 and it should be written as $5n + 2m + 1k$ where $n,m,k$ are the multiplicities of the eigenvalues. Solving the linear problem gives that the characteristic polynomial is $[(x-2)(x-5)]^2$ and the minimal is its root.

Comment: WARNING: Perhaps someone else has said this, but it bears repeating. You've listed $3$ eigenvalues, but the matrix is $4\times 4$, and therefore there *must* be a repeated eigenvalue, so the "distinct eigenvalues implies diagonalizable" does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

Since $(A-I)(A-2I)(A-5I)=0$ the minimal polynomial $m(A)$ is a divisor of $(x-1)(x-2)(x-5)$, hence it has only simple roots, which is a necessary and sufficient condition of diagonalisability.

*Edit*:  concerning the minimal polynomial, we know the eigenvalues are among $\{1,2,5\}$. To determine it, you only have to determine which, among $A-I, A-2I, A-5I$ has a rank  less than $4$.

Comment: You've omitted the part about the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @saulspatz: Oh yes! I'll complete it in a moment